# CUDA shared memory issue in outputs depending on extern declaration and size of array

Tags: cuda

If I am experimenting with shared memory in CUDA and I do not understand its behaviour in this bit of code.
I have a pretty basic kernel:

```
__global__ void sum( int* input, int* output, int size){


  int tid = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x +
    blockDim.x*gridDim.x*blockIdx.y;

  extern  __shared__ int sdata[];

  sdata[tid] = input[tid];
  __syncthreads();

  output[tid] = input[tid];

}
```

And the output is 0 for all `output[]`. However, if I comment out `sdata[tid] = input[tid];`, then the output is fine and equal `input[]`.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something?

[UPDATE]

Well, if I remove the tag `extern` and give a size to the shared array, it seems to work fine. Any ideas why?

[UPDATE]
The way that I am invoking the kernel is from c++ code, so I needed to wrap it to be invoked from the main code.

`kernel.cu` contains the kernel itself plus the wrapper function:

```
void wrapper(int dBlock, int dThread, int* input, int* output, int size){

    sum<<<dBlock,dThread>>>(input, output, size);

}
```

`callerfunction.cpp` contains c++ code and the function that invokes the wrapper.

Comment: How are you invoking the kernel?

Comment: @dbaupp let me update it

Comment: Your code does strange things. Why are you writing to shared memory? It is never used. Your generation of thread ID is strange. Your are launching a kernel with blocks and threads in only X dimension. Why are you offseting the thread ID with blockDim.x*gridDim.x*blockIdx.y?

Comment: @brano it is a generic thread ID index. In this case blockIdx.y is 0, therefore the tid will be as you were expecting. With respect to the use of the shared array, as I said I am experimenting and I created a simple and basic kernel to post it here.

Comment: Yes i realized it. What are you using the shared memory for. You are loading data to it but never using it.

Comment: Originally the idea was to used it for a sum reduction, but I ended up with this problem and I want to used the shared memory for reductions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the extern qualifier you need to pass the size of the shared memory when launching the kernel.

`kernel<<< blocks, threads, size>>>(...)`

The size parameter is the size of shared memory in Bytes.

Comment: thanks but it did not change the result. Declaring it extern in this conditions still will get 0's as output.

Comment: You say when you remove the extern and give it a size it works fine? What is the size of the array? __shared__ sdata[?]

Comment: _\_shared\_\_  sdata[16] in this case. Do you think it could be relevant?

Comment: Than you should pass 16*sizeof(int) as the size of shared memory. But i don't think that this is the only problem. Take a look at my comment above.

Comment: So, you say I need to create a _\_sahred_\_ sdata[16*sizeof(int)] ?

Comment: No, i said that if you want to use the extern qualifier you need to pass 16*sizeof(int) as the size parameter when launching the kernel in the configuration parameters.

Comment: you were right, I wasn't doing it properly and invoking the kernel as you said it works fine. I didn't know you call a kernel in this fashion! Good that I posted this question to learn it!