# CUDA dynamic shared memory not getting value

Tags: cuda

The problem is:

Shared array `perBlockMsg[i]`  holds all values equal to 0, but it is expected to be decimal values larger than 0 as `d_msg[]` has the values. `d_msg[]` ia a 2D array and I have flattened it to 1D and made sure it's data is successfully passed into device.

```
__global__ void add( int *d_msg, int *d_checkSumArray) {

    int i=threadIdx.x;
    int j=blockIdx.x;
    extern  __shared__ int perBlockMsg[];

    if(d_msg[i* gridDim.x + j]<=1)
    {
        perBlockMsg[i]=d_msg[i* gridDim.x + j];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if(j==2 && i<=gridDim.x)  //here i is the row number
    {
        d_checkSumArray[i]=perBlockMsg[i];
    }
}
```

kernel call was as below where (let say ) M=7, R=4  and these 2 variables are dynamic as well

```
add<<<R,(M+R), (M+R)* sizeof(int)>>>( d_msg, d_checkSumArray );
```

Can someone point out where the problem might be?

Comment: You might get some help from this discussion.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900394/cuda-shared-memory-issue-in-outputs-depending-on-extern-declaration-and-size-of

Comment: I maintained the suggestions of the post you mentioned in my above code, but still not working...that is why I post it...

Comment: doesn't this line of code mean you will only get 1, 0, or negative numbers:   if(d_msg[i* gridDim.x + j]<=1)    maybe that should be a greater than or equal test?

Comment: thank you Robert Crovella... this condition was the main matter and now it is resolved... one more thing: how can I use two shared variable like   extern  __shared__ int perBlockMsg[];
 __shared__ int msgLength;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing an answer to get this off the unanswered list.

The principal problem identified in the code was that this test:

```
if(d_msg[i* gridDim.x + j]<=1)
```

was not correct, it should be something like this:

```
if(d_msg[i* gridDim.x + j]>=1)
```

to capture "decimal values larger than 0" as indicated in the question.

Also the follow-up question is covered in the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared) for shared variables.

One approach is to handle all shared variables with a single dynamic allocation (pointer):

```
extern  __shared__ int perBlockMsg[];
int *msgLength = perBlockMsg + perBlockMsgLength;
```